# Can I start the Windows 8 device simulator with a different user account?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, simulator

I noticed that the simulator in VS2012 is (apparently) opening a new Windows session with the same account, which causes many issues:

- I can't use the Modern UI version of IE, because IE is not my default browser. But if I set it as the default browser in the simulator, it also becomes the default browser in my host session, which I don't want
- for apps that are scheduled to start when the session starts, a new instance is started in the simulator. For instance:

  - Dropbox: it could probably cause serious issues if both instances try to synchronize the same physical folder
  - Spark: it detects that someone else connected with the same account from another computer, so I'm disconnected in the host session
  - Logitech Setpoint: it captures the mouse wheel in the simulator, which means I can't use the wheel any more in the host session (I have to kill Setpoint in the simulator to fix it)

It seems to me that the best way to fix this problem would be to have the simulator open a session with a different user account, so that it doesn't interfere with my current session. But I couldn't find any option to control the behavior of the simulator... Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible as Child Sessions are used for the simulator which is a feature that is only available for the current user. More information on Child Sessions can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553447%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

One solution is to virtualize and do a remote debugging on that instance, that way you can deploy and debug without any of the issues above.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441469.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess I'll have to use virtualization then, even though it's not ideal. Could you tell me what is the purpose of child sessions, appart from enabling features like the simulator?

Comment: Very helpful answer, although not what I wanted to hear.

Comment: In a world where sun revolves around Microsoft...
I'm having serious trouble with my dropbox and I'm not planning on removing apps from my win install because Microsoft doesn't FINISH a project before publishing it.

Comment: @RobbieVercammen email me adamt@ the company above, I'd like to get your feedback and hear what issues you are having, I'll pass the feedback on.